# Read file and convert all to UpperCase

Tags: java

I have a small problem. I am reading sort.txt in which there are words ordered like this:

- a
- b
- c
- asv
- sad
- dda

Below you can see my code which converts all of those to UPPERCASE. However I am getting following result:

ABCASVSADDDA

Which should be:

- A
- B
- C
- ASV

and so on

So as you can see it makes them UpperCase but why not every word in each line?

```
public class vlke_crke {


 public static void main (String[] args) {
     try
    {
     FileReader fr = new FileReader("sort.txt");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
     PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("final.txt")));
     String s="";
   while((s = br.readLine()) != null) 
   {
      out.write(s.toUpperCase()+"\n");

    }
  out.close();
  }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Feb, use `out.println(s.toUpperCase())` instead. You wont have to take care of line separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
   while((s = br.readLine()) != null) 
   {
      out.println(s.toUpperCase());

    }
```

or

use "\r\n" instead of "\n" depending on system.

But better one is `println()` as it will take care of line separator that is used in system.

Comment: getting some empty lines beetwen

Comment: I tested 
`out.println(s.toUpperCase());`
and it's working fine.
In what editor you opened the txt file?try notepad

Comment: Maybe you didn't delete `+"\n"` from `out.println(s.toUpperCase()+"\n");`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of \n use System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: Better is println(), as it will take care of `line separator`.